# XPATH Check for a single attribute of current node and then return many attributes

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I would like to search through the XML data and return only some nodes that meet my criteria. Most of the code in my current tests is taken from this site, however I am having trouble writing it the cleanest way.

I know XPATH would be the most efficient, here is my data and my sample code.

Data is provided like this:

```
<pre>
  <Performances>
    <Performance
      performance_id="100042434"
      business_date="08232015"
      show_datetime="1335" 
      reserved_seating="0" 
      auditorium_layout_id="0" 
      performance_number="37654" 
      ticket_price_scheme_index="13" 
      auditorium_index="12" 
      stadium_seat_flag="0" 
      dolby_sound_flag="0" 
      dts_sound_flag="0" 
      thx_sound_flag="0" 
      performance_status_code="0" 
      atm_purchase_flag="1" 
      remote_purchase_flag="1" 
      allow_pass_flag="1" 
      disallow_discount_flag="0" 
      special_engagement_flag="0" 
      feature_code="1502    "
      extended_performance_status_code="O"
    />
  </Performances>
</pre>
```

Performance is the element I need to check... a few hundred.

My code is

```
$XML = simplexml_load_file("BoxOfcXML.326") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

$XMLResults = $XML->xpath('/BoxOfc/Performances/Performance');
foreach($XMLResults as $Result) {
    $Aud = $Result->xpath('//Attribute[@name="auditorium_index"]');

    if($Aud) {
        // because we have a list of elements even if there's one result
        $attributes = $Aud[0]->attributes();
        $AudID = $attributes['value'];
    }
    else {
    // No Author
    }
}
```

But I know the XPath is not correct. I have tried it with different levels //s etc, but I know I am using it wrong.

I can get and compare the data I need using the code below. But if I were to use this method, I would have to rerun the loop again on the same node, once my condition is met because my code is not effective. It would work fine if I JUST wanted to check the date. But I need to check the date, the theatre id, and then return a few more elements.

```
foreach ($perfID->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    if ($a == 'business_date') {
        //collect data we need from each att 
        //set flag if date is today
        //spit it out at the end - 
        if ($b == $today) { echo $b . "<br><br>"; }
    }
}
```

======EDIT=======
Here is working code that will get me what I need. I just have to assume there is a cleaner way to to this.

```
$today = date("mdY");
$XML = simplexml_load_file("BoxOfcXML.326") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$XMLResults = $XML->xpath('/BoxOfc/Performances/Performance');
foreach($XMLResults as $Result) {
    $Details = $Result; //Duplicate it in order to nest the details loop
foreach ($Result->attributes() as $a => $b) {
        if ($a == 'business_date') {    
            if ($b == $today) { 

                foreach ($Details->attributes() as $a => $b) {
                        switch ($a) {
                            case "business_date":
                                echo "$a $b <br>";
                                break;
                            case "show_datetime":
                                echo "$a $b <br>";
                                break;
                            case "auditorium_index":
                                echo "$a $b <br>";
                                break;
                            case "feature_code":
                                echo "$a $b<br><br>";
                                break;

                        }

                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: My data didn't save correctly - sorry

<Performances><Performance performance_id="100042434" business_date="08232015" show_datetime="1335" reserved_seating="0" auditorium_layout_id="0" performance_number="37654" ticket_price_scheme_index="13" auditorium_index="12" stadium_seat_flag="0" dolby_sound_flag="0" dts_sound_flag="0" thx_sound_flag="0" performance_status_code="0" atm_purchase_flag="1" remote_purchase_flag="1" allow_pass_flag="1" disallow_discount_flag="0" special_engagement_flag="0" feature_code="1502    " extended_performance_status_code="O" /></Performances>

Comment: Please clarify, from that sample XML, which attribute you're trying to check and which ones you want to return *exactly*? and what do you mean by *check*? (check the existence, check the value, else?)

Comment: There are usually about 600 <Performance> elements.

I need to check if business_date = today.
If so I will then need to be able to display the other three attributes below.

    business_date="08232015"
    show_datetime="1335"      
    auditorium_index="12"      
    feature_code="1502"

THANKS!

Comment: I edited my original post to include how I am capturing the data I need now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thinck here is what you need.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, can these concepts be applied to php simplexml? I'll give it a shot now I guess!

Comment: In general yes they can. but you should debug your code to get details.